# Where is the Confederation of Owionenseno?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have a 13,000 bounty I want to collect, but can't figure out where to collect it. It says the bounty is in the Confederation of Owionenseno. Does anyone know where this place is? I'm currently docked at Worlidge port in the Thiansi system.

Comment: Have you tried searching the galaxy map for a system called Owionenseno? Not saying that's definitely the name of the system, but it may be.

Answer (score 1):

http://inara.cz/ has the answer to most of those questions. It contains information on almost all inhabited systems and its factions.

In your case,  [Confederation of Owionenseno](http://inara.cz/galaxy-minorfaction/7609) is present in [Owionenseno](http://inara.cz/galaxy-starsystem/10599), as suggested by Dpeif in his comment.

Comment: EDDB is also good for searching for this stuff: https://eddb.io/faction/54889

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different resources you can, and should, use for solving mysteries of faction locations.

Firstly, many factions (including the one you're dealing with) have their home system mentioned in their name. A quick search of the in-game Galaxy Map, using various substrings of the faction name, should help you find these.

Second, there are a number of good Internet-based resources that have data on many of the systems in Elite: Dangerous. This data is all player-submitted, so it is far from comprehensive and in some cases may be out of date. However, if a system is populated (which it would be if a minor faction is there), odds are good that someone has submitted data for it at some point in the past.

INARA (http://inara.cz/) is one such site. From the INARA homepage, click the GALAXY link. Then, click the link for MINOR FACTIONS. From there (http://inara.cz/galaxy-minorfactions), on the right-hand side, you should see a search box. Enter the name of the minor faction you are looking for and press ENTER, or click SEARCH. If your search string is an exact match, you will be taken to the minor faction's page where all of the systems it has been reported in and stations it reportedly controls will be listed.

EDDB (https://eddb.io/) is another good site for these searches. From the EDDB homepage, click on the link for the SYSTEMS search tool. There (https://eddb.io/system), you will need to enter the name of the target faction in the text box labeled "MINOR FACTION". As you type, EDDB will automatically generate a list of matching factions. Once you find the faction name you want, click on that. Then click the FIND SYSTEMS button. If you like, you can also enter a REFERENCE SYSTEM using the same method - this lets EDDB sort the results according to their distance from the given location.

In your case, the Confederation of Owionenseno is only known to exist in one system - their home system, ***Owionenseno***, where they control one station, ***Zalyotin Mine***. For other factions though, you might find they have spread to other neighboring systems which are within easier reach for you. You should be able to claim the bounty at any station where the issuing faction resides. (I'm not 100% sure if the faction needs to control the station or not. However, if they must, both INARA and EDDB provide enough data and search functions to help you nail that down as well.)

For your reference, below are links to the search results for the Confederation of Owionenseno on both INARA and EDDB.

INARA: https://inara.cz/galaxy-minorfaction/7609
EDDB: https://eddb.io/system?u=1&j=54889

Comment: The owning faction issues the bounty. The bounty can be claimed in any system where that faction is present, even if they own nothing in that system.